# Enhanced loop for primitives

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration, primitive-types, listiterator

Is there any short enhanced form of for loop which we can use for primitives.
I have do the legacy code for looping on to primitives, like this

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
}
```

Although for objects, we have ehanced for loop like

```
for(MyObject m : myObjectList){
}
```

Is there any similar option for primitives also?

Comment: If you found a solution (at least what you took for a solution) literally seconds after asking, then why ask at all?

Comment: `for (int x : collection)` works for `int[]` arrays and `List<Integer>` lists, although the latter will throw an NPE if it hits a `null`.

Comment: have you guys tried this `int[] aa ={1,2,3};
  for (int i : aa) {
   System.out.println(i);
  }`

Comment: an array will work.but creating array just for this is a bad idea

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the solution, IntStreams in java 8 can replace the regular for-loop utilizing IntStream.range()

```
IntStream.range(1, 4)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That is not an "enhanced for loop". This is using a completely different API.

Comment: @Tunaki the duplicate you marked seems _a completely different_ question about same topic... maybe this fits better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266570/modern-for-loop-for-primitive-array but....