# How does the enhanced for statement work for arrays, and how to get an iterator for an array?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, foreach

Given the following code snippet:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
for (int i : arr)
    System.out.println(i);
```

I have the following questions:

1. How does the above for-each loop work?
2. How do I get an iterator for an array in Java?
3. Is the array converted to a list to get the iterator?

Comment: A what is faster version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006395/fastest-way-to-iterate-in-java?lq=1

Comment: Above question about performance has been closed. It is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop

Comment: I am not finding an answer to point 1 that is definitive. Does the for each loop test the type of the item being iterated over, and use a regular for loop under the covers if it's an array? Or does it create an Iterable on the fly? Or does it convert to a List? I haven't found a definitive answer to this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want an `Iterator` over an array, you could use one of the direct implementations out there instead of wrapping the array in a `List`. For example:

[Apache Commons Collections `ArrayIterator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/ArrayIterator.html)

Or, this one, if you'd like to use generics:

[`com.Ostermiller.util.ArrayIterator`](http://ostermiller.org/utils/ArrayIterator.java.html)

Note that if you want to have an `Iterator` over primitive types, you can't, because a primitive type can't be a generic parameter. E.g., if you want an `Iterator<int>`, you have to use an `Iterator<Integer>` instead, which will result in a lot of autoboxing and -unboxing if that's backed by an `int[]`.

Comment: Agree. Or build your own ArrayIterator, if you want to keep using the primitive data-type

Comment: Code completion doesn't show any suggestions for `ArrayIt`; assuming all 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 50):

No, there is no conversion. The JVM just iterates over the array using an index in the background.

Quote from Effective Java 2nd Ed., Item 46:

> Note that there is no performance penalty for using
>   the for-each loop, even for arrays. In fact, it may offer a slight performance advantage
>   over an ordinary for loop in some circumstances, as it computes the limit of
>   the array index only once.

So you can't get an `Iterator` for an array (unless of course by converting it to a `List` first).

Comment: Yes, +1 It's prolly just a regular `for`. @Emil, you can't.

Comment: Effective Java is wrong if it's an empty Collection. In that case, it will create an Iterator unnecessarily. This leads to Object churn. The fix is to wrap it in an isEmpty() check. This is particularly important on memory constrained devices like Android.

Comment: Are we sure it's not creating an Iterable for the array, or converting the array to a List? In other words, inside, Java is saying "if the type is an array then use a regular for loop with a hidden index, otherwise, use the Iterable." ???

Answer (score 33):

<s>Arrays.asList(arr).iterator();</s>

Or write your own, implementing ListIterator interface..

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` can not take an `int[]`, only `Object[]` and subclasses.

Comment: this is wrong. this returns a `List<int[]>`, and hence an `Iterator<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`!

Comment: You're converting the array into a list just to provide an iterator ?!

Comment: @KhaledKhnifer There's really not much converting going on. `Arrays.asList()` uses the actual array and wraps it in a class that adapts it to the list interface. So except for the "not supporting primitives" issue (and for people who came here with the same issue in a non-primitive situation) this is actually a good solution.

Comment: @Khaled.K, see Zenexer's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188377/zenexer) new answer.

Answer (score 31):

Google [Guava Librarie](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)s collection provides such function:

```
Iterator<String> it = Iterators.forArray(array);
```

One should prefere Guava over the Apache Collection (which seems to be abandoned).

Comment: This is usually the best answer except when we're dealing with array of primitives (such as `int[]`) then this no longer works :( since we can't specify `Iterator<int>` or `Iterator<Integer>`

Answer (score 15):

In Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).iterator();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
public class ArrayIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  private T array[];
  private int pos = 0;

  public ArrayIterator(T anArray[]) {
    array = anArray;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return pos < array.length;
  }

  public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (hasNext())
      return array[pos++];
    else
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
  }

  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

<s>Strictly speaking, you can't get an iterator of the primitive array, because [Iterator.next()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) can only return an Object.  But through the magic of autoboxing, you can get the iterator using the [Arrays.asList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method.</s>

```
Iterator<Integer> it = Arrays.asList(arr).iterator();
```

The above answer is wrong, you can't use `Arrays.asList()` on a primitive array, it would return a `List<int[]>`. Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s `Ints.asList()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can't directly get an iterator for an array.

But you can use a List, backed by your array, and get an ierator on this list. For that, your array must be an **Integer** array (instead of an int array):

```
Integer[] arr={1,2,3};
List<Integer> arrAsList = Arrays.asList(arr);
Iterator<Integer> iter = arrAsList.iterator();
```

Note: it is only theory. You can get an iterator like this, but I discourage you to do so. Performances are not good compared to a direct iteration on the array with the "extended for syntax".

Note 2: a list construct with this method doesn't support all methods (since the list is backed by the array which have a fixed size). For example, "remove" method of your iterator will result in an exception.

Comment: I don't think it will work.Arrays.asList(arr) will return List of type int[].Since it is primitive array.

Comment: @Emil: Java generics don’t work for primitive types. `Arrays.asList` implicitly takes care of this by boxing the values in the array. Hence, the result really *is* a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @emil it works because Arrays.asList takes a varargs parameter

Comment: @seanizer:but i tried the above code in my IDE and it shows error.

Comment: it compiles in my eclipse. have you set the compiler compliance to at least 1.5 ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the game, but I noticed some key points that were left out, particularly regarding Java 8 and the efficiency of `Arrays.asList`.

## 1. How does the for-each loop work?

As [Ciro Santilli 六四事件 法轮功 包卓轩](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%e5%85%ad%e5%9b%9b%e4%ba%8b%e4%bb%b6-%e6%b3%95%e8%bd%ae%e5%8a%9f-%e5%8c%85%e5%8d%93%e8%bd%a9) pointed out, there's a handy utility for examining bytecode that ships with the JDK: `javap`.  Using that, we can determine that the following two code snippets produce identical bytecode as of Java 8u74:

### For-each loop:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
for (int n : arr) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

### For loop:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};

{  // These extra braces are to limit scope; they do not affect the bytecode
    int[] iter = arr;
    int length = iter.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int n = iter[i];
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

## 2. How do I get an iterator for an array in Java?

While this doesn't work for primitives, it should be noted that converting an array to a List with `Arrays.asList` does not impact performance in any significant way.  The impact on both memory and performance is nearly immeasurable.

`Arrays.asList` does not use a normal List implementation that is readily accessible as a class.  It uses `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, which is not the same as `java.util.ArrayList`.  It is a very thin wrapper around an array and cannot be resized.  Looking at the source code for `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, we can see that it's designed to be functionally equivalent to an array.  There is almost no overhead.  Note that I have omitted all but the most relevant code and added my own comments.

```
public class Arrays {
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a);
    }

    private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable {
        private final E[] a;

        ArrayList(E[] array) {
            a = Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return a.length;
        }

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return a[index];
        }

        @Override
        public E set(int index, E element) {
            E oldValue = a[index];
            a[index] = element;
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The iterator is at `java.util.AbstractList.Itr`.  As far as iterators go, it's very simple; it just calls `get()` until `size()` is reached, much like a manual for loop would do.  It's the simplest and usually most efficient implementation of an `Iterator` for an array.

Again, `Arrays.asList` does not create a `java.util.ArrayList`.  It's much more lightweight and suitable for obtaining an iterator with negligible overhead.

### Primitive arrays

As others have noted, `Arrays.asList` can't be used on primitive arrays.  Java 8 introduces several new technologies for dealing with collections of data, several of which could be used to extract simple and relatively efficient iterators from arrays.  Note that if you use generics, you're always going to have the boxing-unboxing problem: you'll need to convert from int to Integer and then back to int.  While boxing/unboxing is usually negligible, it does have an O(1) performance impact in this case and could lead to problems with very large arrays or on computers with very limited resources (i.e., [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip)).

My personal favorite for any sort of array casting/boxing operation in Java 8 is the new stream API.  For example:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
Iterator<Integer> iterator = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).iterator();
```

The streams API also offers constructs for avoiding the boxing issue in the first place, but this requires abandoning iterators in favor of streams.  There are dedicated stream types for int, long, and double (IntStream, LongStream, and DoubleStream, respectively).

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(arr);
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Interestingly, Java 8 also adds `java.util.PrimitiveIterator`.  This provides the best of both worlds: compatibility with `Iterator<T>` via boxing along with methods to avoid boxing.  PrimitiveIterator has three built-in interfaces that extend it: OfInt, OfLong, and OfDouble.  All three will box if `next()` is called but can also return primitives via methods such as `nextInt()`.  Newer code designed for Java 8 should avoid using `next()` unless boxing is absolutely necessary.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator = Arrays.stream(arr);

// You can use it as an Iterator<Integer> without casting:
Iterator<Integer> example = iterator;

// You can obtain primitives while iterating without ever boxing/unboxing:
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    // Would result in boxing + unboxing:
    //int n = iterator.next();

    // No boxing/unboxing:
    int n = iterator.nextInt();

    System.out.println(n);
}
```

If you're not yet on Java 8, sadly your simplest option is a lot less concise and is almost certainly going to involve boxing:

```
final int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
Iterator<Integer> iterator = new Iterator<Integer>() {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i < arr.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        return arr[i++];
    }
};
```

Or if you want to create something more reusable:

```
public final class IntIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private final int[] arr;
    private int i = 0;

    public IntIterator(int[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i < arr.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        return arr[i++];
    }
}
```

You could get around the boxing issue here by adding your own methods for obtaining primitives, but it would only work with your own internal code.

## 3. Is the array converted to a list to get the iterator?

No, it is not.  However, that doesn't mean wrapping it in a list is going to give you worse performance, provided you use something lightweight such as `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: The most complete answer in my opinion, but I think you should replace `mapToObj(Integer::new)` with `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`

Comment: It seems [you're right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-), @MichaelSchmeißer.  Thanks for the tip.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

### How does the above for-each loop work?

Like many other array features, the JSL mentions arrays explicitly and gives them magical properties. [JLS 7 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

```
EnhancedForStatement:

    for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement
```

> [...]
>
> If the type of Expression is a subtype of `Iterable`, then the translation is as follows
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, the Expression necessarily has an array type, `T[]`. [[ MAGIC! ]]
>
> Let `L1 ... Lm` be the (possibly empty) sequence of labels immediately preceding the enhanced for statement.
>
> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```

> `#a` and `#i` are automatically generated identifiers that are distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in scope at the point where the enhanced for statement occurs.

### Is the array converted to a list to get the iterator?

Let's `javap` it up:

```
public class ArrayForLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
        for (int i : arr)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

then:

```
javac ArrayForLoop.java
javap -v ArrayForLoop
```

`main` method with a bit of editing to make it easier to read:

```
 0: iconst_3
 1: newarray       int
 3: dup
 4: iconst_0
 5: iconst_1
 6: iastore
 7: dup
 8: iconst_1
 9: iconst_2
10: iastore
11: dup
12: iconst_2
13: iconst_3
14: iastore

15: astore_1
16: aload_1
17: astore_2
18: aload_2
19: arraylength
20: istore_3
21: iconst_0
22: istore        4

24: iload         4
26: iload_3
27: if_icmpge     50
30: aload_2
31: iload         4
33: iaload
34: istore        5
36: getstatic     #2    // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
39: iload         5
41: invokevirtual #3    // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
44: iinc          4, 1
47: goto          24
50: return
```

Breakdown:

- `0` to `14`: create the array
- `15` to `22`: prepare for the for loop. At **22**, store integer `0` from stack into local position `4`. THAT is the loop variable.
- `24` to `47`: the loop. The loop variable is retrieved at `31`, and incremented at `44`. When it equals the array length which is stored in local variable 3 on the check at `27`, the loop ends.

**Conclusion**: it is the same as doing an explicit for loop with an index variable, no itereators involved.

Answer (score 3):

For (2), Guava provides exactly what you want as [Int.asList()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29).  There is an equivalent for each primitive type in the associated class, e.g., `Booleans` for `boolean`, etc.

```
    int[] arr={1,2,3};
    for(Integer i : Ints.asList(arr)) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a recent student but I BELIEVE the original example with int[] is iterating over the primitives array, but not by using an Iterator object.  It merely has the same (similar) syntax with different contents,

```
for (primitive_type : array) { }

for (object_type : iterableObject) { }
```

Arrays.asList() APPARENTLY just applies List methods to an object array that it's given - but for any other kind of object, including a primitive array, iterator().next() APPARENTLY just hands you the reference to the original object, treating it as a list with one element.  Can we see source code for this?  Wouldn't you prefer an exception?  Never mind.  I guess (that's GUESS) that it's like (or it IS) a singleton Collection.  So here asList() is irrelevant to the case with a primitives array, but confusing.  I don't KNOW I'm right, but I wrote a program that says that I am.

Thus this example (where basically asList() doesn't do what you thought it would, and therefore is not something that you'd actually use this way) - I hope the code works better than my marking-as-code, and, hey, look at that last line:

```
// Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_19-b04)

import java.util.*;

public class Page0434Ex00Ver07 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ii = new int[4];
    ii[0] = 2;
    ii[1] = 3;
    ii[2] = 5;
    ii[3] = 7;

    Arrays.asList(ii);

    Iterator ai = Arrays.asList(ii).iterator();

    int[] i2 = (int[]) ai.next();

    for (int i : i2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(12345678).iterator().next());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer from 30thh using `Iterators` from Guava. However, from some frameworks I get null instead of an empty array, and `Iterators.forArray(array)` does not handle that well. So I came up with this helper method, which you can call with `Iterator<String> it = emptyIfNull(array);`

```
public static <F> UnmodifiableIterator<F> emptyIfNull(F[] array) {
    if (array != null) {
        return Iterators.forArray(array);
    }
    return new UnmodifiableIterator<F>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return false;
        }

        public F next() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```