# Convert Java Array to Iterable

Tags: java, arrays, iterable

I have an Array of primitives, for example for int, int[] foo. It might be a small sized one, or not.

```
int foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
```

What is the best way to create an `Iterable<Integer>` from it?

```
Iterable<Integer> fooBar = convert(foo);
```

Notes:

Please do not answer using loops (unless you can give a good explanation on how the compiler do something smart about them?)

Also note that

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(a);
```

Will not even compile

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>
```

Also check
[Why is an array not assignable to Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)
before answering.

Also, if you use some library (e.g., Guava), please explain why this is the Best. ( Because its from Google is not a complete answer :P )

Last, since there seems to be a homework about that, avoid posting homeworkish code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterator for array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912765/iterator-for-array)

Comment: Add them to an LinkedList then just return the iterator of that Set.

Answer (score 145):

```
Integer foo[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(foo);
// or
Iterable<Integer> iterable = Arrays.asList(foo);
```

Though you need to use an `Integer` array (not an `int` array) for this to work.

For primitives, you can use guava:

```
Iterable<Integer> fooBar = Ints.asList(foo);
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>15.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

For Java8 with lambdas: (Inspired by [Jin Kwon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33739694/363573))

```
final int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
final Iterable<Integer> i1 = () -> Arrays.stream(arr).iterator();
final Iterable<Integer> i2 = () -> IntStream.of(arr).iterator();
final Iterable<Integer> i3 = () -> IntStream.of(arr).boxed().iterator();
```

Comment: Two notes: 1) he has `int`, not `Integer` 2) `List` is already `Iterable` so the third line is pointless.

Comment: he needs Iterable that why there is third line.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd lines are options i would say :)

Comment: This is not part of a homework, I was just trying to avoid duplicating code for a debugging function processing the contents of an array or list... While looking around I did indeed find Arrays.asList(..);, but at least Eclipse seems to think it will not do what i want (e.g., It infers the result of Arrays.asList(foo) as a List<int[]>, not List<Integer>...) I found this interesting enough for a question... (-Breaking comment in parts cause of limits-)

Comment: In general one could think of a lot of ways to do it, but I was wondering what is the BEST (for example a loop would imho be mush slower compared to ...{well, the problem is I cannot think of anything!:) }) Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable for a discussion on why, my question though is not why, but how, and what type of container would be best (why ArrayList? In fact,I could imagine some AbstractList wrapper using Generics.. , Probably depends on the size...)

Comment: BTW, I later remembered that I could use Arrays.toString() for what I needed, but converting should be useful in a bunch of cases...

Comment: A loop on array will not be slow, arrays are the fastest among all, as it is a sequence of memory blocks and looping means reading sequential memory blocks as is never slow comparing to other similar data objects.

Answer (score 51):

just my 2 cents:

```
final int a[] = {1,2,3};

java.lang.Iterable<Integer> aIterable=new Iterable<Integer>() {

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
       return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            private int pos=0;

            public boolean hasNext() {
               return a.length>pos;
            }

            public Integer next() {
               return a[pos++];
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove an element of an array.");
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: remove() is not neccessary in java 8, because it is a default method which throws UnsupportedOperationException. Only if you want to supply a better explanation message.

Comment: +1 I do something similar to create an `Iterator<Character>` from a `String`. Implementing your own `Iterator` seems like the only way to avoid needlessly iterating through all of the values to convert from the object type to the primitive type (via Guava's `Ints.asList()` for example), just to be able to get an `Iterator` from the `List` that was created.

Comment: You are right Alex. 
Default methods were added to Java 8. 
In 2013 I added this ancient piece of code here.

Answer (score 36):

With Java 8, you can do this.

```
final int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
final PrimitiveIterator.OfInt i1 = Arrays.stream(arr).iterator();
final PrimitiveIterator.OfInt i2 = IntStream.of(arr).iterator();
final Iterator<Integer> i3 = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().iterator();
```

Answer (score 20):

Guava provides the adapter you want as [Int.asList()](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/9d60a8f5941265876f21a0ed7b37b8b224461a82/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.java#L537).  There is an equivalent for each primitive type in the associated class, e.g., `Booleans` for `boolean`, etc.

```
int foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
Iterable<Integer> fooBar = Ints.asList(foo);
for(Integer i : fooBar) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The suggestions above to use `Arrays.asList` won't work, even if they compile because you get an `Iterator<int[]>` rather than `Iterator<Integer>`.  What happens is that rather than creating a list backed by your array, you created a 1-element list of arrays, containing your array.

Comment: just a note: the link isn't working anymore. Github link: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.java

Comment: Thanks @Passi, fixed (can't seem to find a Google supported way to link to javadoc anymore so I linked to the source you provided).

Answer (score 11):

In Java 8 or later, `Iterable` is a functional interface returns `Iterator`.
So you can do this.

```
static Iterable<Integer> convert(int[] array) {
    return () -> Arrays.stream(array).iterator();
}
```

and

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
Iterable<Integer> iterable = convert(array);
for (int i : iterable)
    System.out.println(i);
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
final YourType[] yourArray = ...;
return new Iterable<YourType>() {
  public Iterator<YourType> iterator() {
     return Iterators.forArray(yourArray);   // Iterators is a Google guava utility
  }
}
```

The iterator itself is a lazy `UnmodifiableIterator` but that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I can only agree that `Arrays.asList(T...)` is clearly the best solution for Wrapper types or arrays with non-primtive datatypes. This method calls a constructor of a simple private static `AbstractList` implementation in the `Arrays` class which basically saves the given array reference as field and simulates a list by overriding the needed methods.
If you can choose between a primtive type or a Wrapper type for your array, I would use the Wrapper type for such situations but of course, it's not always useful or required.
There would be only two possibilities you can do:
1) You can create a class with a static method for each primitive datatype array (`boolean, byte, short, int, long, char, float, double` returning an `Iterable<`WrapperType`>`. These methods would use anonymous classes of `Iterator` (besides `Iterable`) which are allowed to contain the reference of the comprising method's argument (for example an `int[]`) as field in order to implement the methods.

*-> This approach is performant and saves you memory (except for the memory of the newly created methods, even though, using `Arrays.asList()` would take memory in the same way)*
2) Since arrays don't have methods (as to be read on the side you linked) they can't provide an `Iterator` instance either. If you really are too lazy to write new classes, you must use an instance of an already existing class that implements `Iterable` because there is no other way around than instantiating `Iterable` or a subtype.
The ONLY way to create an existing Collection derivative implementing `Iterable` is to use a loop (except you use anonymous classes as described above) or you instantiate an `Iterable` implementing class whose constructor allows a primtive type array (because `Object[]` doesn't allow arrays with primitive type elements) but as far as I know, the Java API doesn't feature a class like that.
The reason for the loop can be explained easily:
for each Collection you need Objects and primtive datatypes aren't objects. Objects are much bigger than primitive types so that they require additional data which must be generated for each element of the primitive type array. That means if two ways of three (using `Arrays.asList(T...)` or using an existing Collection) require an aggregate of objects, you need to create for each primitive value of your `int[]` array the wrapper object. The third way would use the array as is and use it in an anonymous class as I think it's preferable due to fast performance.
There is also a third strategy using an `Object` as argument for the method where you want to use the array or `Iterable` and it would require type checks to figure out which type the argument has, however I wouldn't recommend it at all as you usually need to consider that the Object hasn't always the required type and that you need seperate code for certain cases.
In conclusion, it's the fault of Java's problematic Generic Type system which doesn't allow to use primitive types as generic type which would save a lot of code by using simply `Arrays.asList(T...)`. So you need to program for each primitive type array, you need, such a method (which basically makes no difference to the memory used by a C++ program which would create for each used type argument a seperate method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IterableOf`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.23/org/cactoos/iterable/IterableOf.html) from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
Iterable<String> names = new IterableOf<>(
  "Scott Fitzgerald", "Fyodor Dostoyevsky"
);
```

Then, you can turn it into a list using [`ListOf`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.23/org/cactoos/list/ListOf.html):

```
List<String> names = new ListOf<>(
  new IterableOf<>(
    "Scott Fitzgerald", "Fyodor Dostoyevsky"
  )
);
```

Or simply this:

```
List<String> names = new ListOf<>(
  "Scott Fitzgerald", "Fyodor Dostoyevsky"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

While a similar answer has already been sort of posted, I think the reason to use the new PrimitiveIterator.OfInt was not clear. A good solution is to use Java 8 PrimitiveIterator since it's specialized for primitive int types (and avoids the extra boxing/unboxing penalty):

```
    int[] arr = {1,2,3};
    // If you use Iterator<Integer> here as type then you can't get the actual benefit of being able to use nextInt() later
    PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator = Arrays.stream(arr).iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.nextInt());
        // Use nextInt() instead of next() here to avoid extra boxing penalty
    }
```

Ref: https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/jdk8u12-docs/api/java/util/PrimitiveIterator.OfInt.html

Answer (score -2):

In java8 IntSteam stream can be boxed to stream of Integers.

```
public static Iterable<Integer> toIterable(int[] ints) {
    return IntStream.of(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I think performance matters based on the size of the array.