# Arrays.asList returns List of int[] when an int array is passed however returns List of String when String[] is passed

Tags: java

Arrays.asList returns List of int[]  when an int array is passed however it returns List of String when String[] is passed and not List of String[]

```
int ai[]={1,2};
List<int[]> aiList=Arrays.asList(ai);
```

same is not true for Strings ..Any reason

```
String[] str={"a","b"};  //string array
List<String> strlist=Arrays.asList(str); //valid statement

Below is not valid
String[] str={"a","b"};
List<String[]> strlist=Arrays.asList(str);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422025/arrays-aslistint-not-working

Comment: your arrays is made of primitives that is the reason

Comment: The reason for this behavior is because String is not a primitive type in Java.

Same is the case with `Integers`. Following code is valid:

    `Integer[] ints = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ints);`

But this is not:

    `Integer[] ints = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    List<Integer[]> list = Arrays.asList(ints);`

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you are trying to create a list with each element in it is an array of Strings. This is not matching the type on the right side is is a list of Strings.