# Stream.of(int[]) returns Stream<int[]> whereas Stream.of(String[]) returns Stream<String> why?

Tags: java

`Stream.of(int[])` returns `Stream<int[]>`, whereas `Stream.of(String[])`
returns `Stream<String>`.

Why are the two methods are behaving differently? Both should have either returned
`Stream<int>` and `Stream<String>` or `Stream<int[]>` and `Stream<String[]>`.

```
static int intArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
static String stringArr[] = { "3", "6", "8","14", "15" }; 

Stream<int[]> stream = Stream.of(intArr);
Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of(stringArr);
```

Comment: Because primitives don't work well with generics. The `int[]` is interpreted as one object, and is thus one element in the array passed to `Stream.of`.

Comment: `Stream.of(int[])` cannot return a `Stream<int>` because an `int` is not an `Object`.

Comment: When you pass `String[]` array to `Stram::of` it will be interpreted as if you passed strings one by one because of `varargs` parameter of `Stram::of` method.

Comment: ok , i understood the difference now , when I changed array from int to Integer then it is returning correctly  Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(intArr);  Thanks all :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422025/arrays-aslistint-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing `Stream<int>`, just like there's no `List<int>`. Generic type parameters cannot be substituted with primitive types.

For a stream of (primitive) `int` elements there's `IntStream`. `IntStream.of(int... values)` and `Arrays.stream(int[] array)` will both give you an `IntStream`, whose elements are `int`, where you pass an `int[]` to them.

Comment: Yes Eran you are right thanks a lot for quick clarification ;)