# Stream API reduce method not working while adding elements

Tags: java

I am trying to add elements of int array using Stream API.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int sum = Arrays.asList(a).stream().reduce(0, (psum, x) -> psum+x);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

But its is giving this error message.

```
E:\Java\StreamAPI\src\Main.java:6:44
java: no suitable method found for reduce(int,(psum,x)->psum + x)
    method java.util.stream.Stream.reduce(int[],java.util.function.BinaryOperator<int[]>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to int[])
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<U>reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction<U,? super int[],U>,java.util.function.BinaryOperator<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

I even tried doing this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int sum = Arrays.asList(a).stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I got this error message:

```
E:\Java\StreamAPI\src\Main.java:6:44
java: no suitable method found for reduce(int,Integer::sum)
    method java.util.stream.Stream.reduce(int[],java.util.function.BinaryOperator<int[]>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to int[])
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<U>reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction<U,? super int[],U>,java.util.function.BinaryOperator<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Both of these examples were given in this Baeldung [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) about reduce in stream api.

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31422046/11434552) that addresses your issue.  Basically you can change `int[]` to `Integer[]` and it would work, though I recommend following @Louis Wasserman's answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `Arrays.asList(int[])` doesn't do what you think it does.  It creates a list with a single element, an integer array.  It does not create a list containing several integers.  (And note that the Baeldung article you link doesn't use `Array.asList` on an `int[]`, either.)

Instead, write `Arrays.stream(a).reduce(0, Integer::sum)`, or even `Arrays.stream(a).sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is, that you input a `int[]` into the `Arrays.ofList`-method.

The return type of the call `Arrays.ofList(int[])` would be `List<int[]>`, which is currently not supported. Thus it is being interpreted you wanting a list with only a single element of type `int[]`.

To circumvent that, you can either declare the list using the boxed types (`Integer`, `Double`, etc.) or use different Methods to generate a stream of integers.

## Solution 1: Use Boxed Types

```java
Integer[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int sum = Arrays.asList(a).stream().reduce(0, (psum, x) -> psum+x);
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```

## Solution 2: Use Arrays.asList with varargs directly

```java
int sum = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().reduce(0, (psum, x) -> psum+x);
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```

## Solution 3: Use Stream with varargs directly

Similar to the previous solution but generating directly the stream without an intermediate list.

```java
int sum = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).reduce(0, (psum, x) -> psum+x);
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```

## Solution 4: Use IntStream with varargs directly

Java offers multiple different types of `Stream` one of them being `IntStream`.
This offers an unboxed version for primitives.

```java
int sum = IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5).reduce(0, (psum, x) -> psum+x);
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```

## Bonus

An alternative to using `reduce(0, (psum, x) -> psum+x)` would be using some adding-operation.

You could use `Integer.sum(int a, int b)` which fulfills the contract of `reduce`.

```java
int sum = IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```

Using an `IntStream` offers an additional benefit having the method `sum()`.

```java
int sum = IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```

In case you are not able to generate an `IntStream` yourself and need to work with a `Stream<Integer>`, you can also map to an `IntStream`.

```java
int sum = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()
System.out.println(sum);
// prints 15
```