# array-element:array-name in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, foreach

Below is an example program from some notes on how to use the **for** loop in Java. I don't understand how the line `element:arrayname` works. Can someone briefly explain it, or provide a link to a page that does?

```
public class foreachloop {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int [] smallprimes= new int [3]; 
        smallprimes[0]=2;
        smallprimes[1]=3;
        smallprimes[2]=5;

        // for each loop
        for (int element:smallprimes) {
            System.out.println("smallprimes="+element);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not a constructor. it's a valid for loop. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912765/iterator-for-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another way to say: `for each element in the array smallprimes.`

It's equivalent to

```
for (int i=0; i< smallprimes.length; i++)
{
     int element=smallprimes[i];
     System.out.println("smallprimes="+element);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the so called *enhanced for statement*. It iterates over `smallprimes` and it turn assignes each element to the variable `element`.

See the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(declaration : expression)
```

The two pieces of the for statement are:

**declaration** The newly declared block variable, of a type compatible with
the elements of the array you are accessing. This variable will be available
within the for block, and its value will be the same as the current array
element.
 **expression** This must evaluate to the array you want to loop through.
This could be an array variable or a method call that returns an array. The
array can be any type: primitives, objects, even arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a constructor. `for (int i : smallPrimes)` declares an `int i` variable, scoped in the `for` loop.

The `i` variable is updated at the beginning of each iteration with a value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not constructors in your code snippet it seems you are confused with terminology.

There is public static method `main()` here. This method is an entry point to any java program. It is called by JVM on startup.

The first line creates 3 elements `int` array `smallprimes`. This actually allocates memory for 3 sequential int values. Then you put values to those array elements. Then you iterate over the array using `for` *operator* (not function!) and print the array elements.