# Iterator of Object[]

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Is there a way to obtain the iterator of an array? Something like that:

```
class MyCollection implements Iterable<String> {

   String[] items;

   @Override
   public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return items.iterator(); //obviously, it doesn't compile.
   }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912765/iterator-for-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
return Arrays.asList(items).iterator();
```

It simply wraps the array in a list implementation so that you can just call the `iterator()` method on it.

Be aware that this approach will only works with array of objects. For primitive arrays you would have to implement your own iterator (with an anonymous class for instance).

---

As of Java 8, you could also use [`Arrays.stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) to get an iterator out of the box (and make this code compiling also if `items` is an `int[]`, `double[]` or `long[]`):

```
return Arrays.stream(items).iterator();
```

though you won't be able for the primitive data types `char`, `float` and `short` as there are no corresponding stream implementations. You could however use this workaround:

```
return IntStream.range(0, items.length).mapToObj(i -> items[i]).iterator();
```

Comment: Good point about primitive arrays. Will remove my answer, and just add the link to yours, as that's basically all mine has in favour of it.

Answer (score 1):

you could always define your own iterator

```
public class ArrayItterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
    private final T[] array;
    int i = 0;
    public ArrayItterator(T[] array) {
        super();
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { 
          return i<array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() { 
          return array[i++];
    }

}
```

and then use it

```
@Override
   public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator<String>(items);
   }
```