# How exactly does an enhanced for-loop iterate over primitive types?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, iterator

I know an enhanced for-loop (since java 1.5) can be used to iterate over collections of class-types that implement the Iterator interface. It can however also be used to iterate over arrays of primitive types e.g. int, boolean,...
So my logical conclusion was that thanks to autoboxing and unboxing, for example, primitve integers were being wrapped inside  their reference-type which would then on their turn, implement Iteratable.

However, when I looked up the documentation of `java.lang.Integer`, nowhere is mentioned any extension or implementation of a superclass or interface that could implement or extend the `Iterable` interface. How does an enhanced for-loop know how to loop over primitive types without the `Iterable` interface being implemented?

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912765/how-does-the-enhanced-for-statment-work-for-arrays-and-how-to-get-an-iterator-f, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

You're looking in the wrong place. It's not the *entries* that would need to be iterable, it's the *array* that would need to be. But the real answer is that the enhanced for loop has native support for looping through arrays. E.g., it's for looping through arrays *and*, separately, iterables. Seel [JLS§14.14.2 - *The enhanced for statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), which gives two possible uses:

> - If the type of *Expression* is a subtype of `Iterable`, then the translation is as follows.
>
>   *(...specifies algorithm for looping through `Iterable`...)*
> - Otherwise, the *Expression* necessarily has an array type, `T[]`.
>
>   *(...specifies algorithm for looping through `T[]` array...)*