# Java: does Loop list twice drain double power?

Tags: java, list, libgdx

With LibGDX comes a example which use the  MVC pattern.

the updater looks something like this

```
List<Enemies> enemies = new List<Enemies>();

public void update() {
updateEnemies();
checkCollision();
}

void updateEnemies() {
 for each enemy //Loop enemies list{
   enemy.update();
  }

}

void checkCollison(){
   for each enemy//Loop enemies list{
    if(enemy.overlaps(hero.bounds) {
       //Do stuff
    }
   }
}
```

Now it loops through enemeies list twice. Should I do this? Maybe not one small list but I want to add lots of lots of lists so should I merge them?

Cheers!

Comment: I want to do something similar but do not know the answer, i used several lists before, but it would be good to know the answer

Comment: You'd reduce the time if you merge the actions. But do you often update without checking collisions, or do you always do both?

Comment: update = update position state so on
Collison does collison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iteration itself is cheap, and is unlikely to be the source of any performance problems. Nothing, however, is guaranteed; if you want to understand the performance characteristics of your program, use a profiler.

Answer (score 2):

**Be warned.** In updating all enemies they all take new positions. And then collisions are checked. If you would do in a loop: update one enemy and check collision, you would check on obsolete positions of some enemies. This might be irrelevant, or not. *A java comment would be in order: // First update all enemies: ... // Now we can for the new positions: .*

As answer: overhead is minimal.

Comment: overhead?...sorry what does that mean?

Comment: I was going to write something similar, until I realized that the code only checks for collisions with the *hero*, whose position doesn't appear to be changed by either of the loops.

Comment: AndroidXTr3meN: overhead = costs; really tiny as others said. For @aix thanks for stating that.

Answer (score 2):

From the code above, one can see that the performance should be good as the loop you are using is performance-friendly:

```
for (Enemies enemy : enemies)
{
    //Do something here
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006395/fastest-way-to-iterate-in-java).

Comment: Thanks, but I meant more if I use the loop twice

Comment: The same thing will happen to the maximum times, because this loop type gives most on the performance side in the other loop types. so it's not arguable.

Comment: You could do that of course according to the GUI accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
for each element in collection
   operationA();
   operationB();
end for
```

takes basically the same time as doing:

```
for each element in collection
   operationA();
end for
for each element in collection
   operationB();
end for
```

Yet, the second option may be clearer as each loop has a specific goal and not everything is mixed up in the same loop.

Comment: I find that hard to believe it takes the same time.  If my collection is 12 trillion items it will be twice as long.

Comment: I agree, it would take more time. But depending on the size of the list it could be negligible.

Comment: Actually, n * (a + b) = n * a + n * b. There might be a little overhead if the execution time of one operation is VERY short!

Comment: Well im thinking that if I merge them and enlarge my game it might ruin the design and make it unclear. or?

Comment: It might. All I am saying is that it is often better to have n blocks of code doing n specific things you clearly understand and can easily maintain than having one block of code doing n things (and sometimes mixing them!). And that's specially true if there is no performance issue.

Comment: Thanks! I design the code so I can easily change if I change my mind or I get performance Issue

Comment: In general, you should write your code to be readable, measure performance, and then fix bottlenecks if you need better performance.  You can conjecture all day about what will make it run faster, but you use measurements to guarantee you get the "bang for your buck" when you add optimizations

Answer (score 0):

In theory, once the code is executed, the compiler might merge both loops together, or optimize it in a better way. Sometimes things do not get exactly executed the way they seem to be put together.

Comment: The compiler execute the code from line 0 til last line in order. Atleast what I've heard

Comment: thats what you see when you debug it, but not what the compiler sees.

Answer (score 0):

Merging loops will introduce new overhead, unexpected intervals... Instead, using same loops for different methods doesn't affect performance in practice, it keeps your code clear, more readable and maintainable. Catching exceptions and other custom tasks with each method can be easily handled if those methods.