# Fastest way to check if an array of boolean contains true

Tags: java

I have an `array` of `boolean` entries:

```
boolean[] myBooleanArray = new boolean[24];
```

Currently i check if it contains true like so:

```
Arrays.asList(myBooleanArray).contains(true);
```

Is this the *fastest* way to check an array of boolean? If not, what is the fastest way to perform this check?

EDIT:

I timed the methods in your answers as follows by running it as an app on an Android 4.03 Samsung S2 device:

```
boolean[] myBooleanArray = new boolean[24];

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
suggestedMethod(myBooleanArray);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
Log.i("timetest", Long.toString(duration));
```

Time ranking over five runs were, with fastest first:

1. Between 5334 and 11584 ns:

   ```
   for (boolean value : myBooleanArray) {
       if (value) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
   ```
2. Between 160542 and 171417 ns:

   ```
   Arrays.asList(myBooleanArray).contains(true);
   ```
3. Between 191833 and 205750 ns:

   ```
   Booleans.contains(myBooleanArray, true);
   ```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(myBooleanArray)` gives you list of arrays not `Boolean`s. That method should not be used with arrays of primitives.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark your various options and see rather than believing others?

Comment: @Rohit Jain. Fair point, but I'm not experienced enough to know what all the options are. With these answers I can do a benchmark.

Comment: @PierreRymiortz.. Hmm. Yeah right.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. See edited answer for benchmarking of methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just iterate through array

```
for(boolean value: myBooleanArray){
  if(value){ return true;}
}
return false;
```

Comment: OP just want to check presence of `true`, its not about all the `true`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (which has a lot of useful stuff):

```
Booleans.contains(myBooleanArray, true);
```

([JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html#contains%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29))

The documentation of this method also describes another way. You can replace a `boolean[]` with a `BitSet` (should be more memory efficient) and call `!bitSet.isEmpty()` to check whether at least one bit is true.

Comment: Is this the fastest way ? Because it is also doing the same by using contains method as it is also in question.

Comment: I cannot think of any faster way for a boolean array (but the BitSet might actually be faster).

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, if you have an array (or `List`) of anything, the fastest/onlyest way to look for an item in it is to iterate over the array until you find what you're looking for. That's one of the limitations of arrays/`List`s.

For an array of 24 elements, I wouldn't worry about this anyway. If you had millions of items and expected very few `true`s (or possibly none), then it could make sense to encapsulate the data in a class:

```
public class BooleanArray
{
    boolean[] arr = new boolean[SIZE]; // or get size from a constructor
    boolean anyTrue = false;

    boolean get(int index) {
        return arr[index];
    }

    boolean set(int index, boolean value) {
        arr[index] = value;
        anyTrue |= value;
    }

    boolean containsAnyTrues() {
        return anyTrue;
    }
}
```

To reiterate, I don't suggest this for your array of 24 elements. I mean it more of an example that your data structure should support the expected use case. If the expected use case is "lots of elements, very sparse `true`s, need to find out if there are any `true`s" then your concern for the fastest way is more relevant, and a data structure like the one above would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006395/fastest-way-to-iterate-in-java) iterating over an array is mostly the same using enhanced for or normal for because both use array accesses . So just iterate over your array:

```
public boolean containsTrue(boolean[] array){

    for(boolean val : array){
        if(val)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had an array of 0's and 1's, you could simply OR every element. If you get a 1, you know there is atleast one TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to an *Array* of boolean, you should give a look to the class [`java.util.BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html). Despite the name, it is more array-like than set-like.

The method [`BitSet.isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#isEmpty()) is answering your question if there is any `true` in the "Array", and it is implemented as:

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return wordsInUse == 0;
}
```

I doubt that you can get a faster check …

But the price has to be paid elsewhere: setting/unsetting a value might be more expensive as for a mere `boolean []`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the array, and the array is large. Eg. 24 is pretty small so it would be hard to improve. Arrays.mismatch seems to be a bit quicker.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class BenchMark{
    final static int N = Short.MAX_VALUE;
    static boolean[] base = new boolean[N];
    static boolean any1(boolean[] test){
        return Arrays.mismatch(base, test)==-1;
    }
    static boolean any2(boolean[] test){
        for(boolean b: test)
            if(b) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean[] test = new boolean[N];
        Random r = new Random(1);
        int last = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int p = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++){
            test[last] = false;
            int s = r.nextInt(2);
            if(s == 0){
                last = r.nextInt(test.length);
                test[last] = true;
            } 
            if(any2(test)){
                p++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( ( p + " in " + (System.nanoTime() - start ) / 1e9 ) + " seconds");
    }
}
```

I didn't setup a proper benchmark, but the output from this shows `any1` to be about 4-5 times faster than `any2`, the standard loop technique.

To understand why, looking in the jdk source code. We find [vectorizedMismatch](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/a7830958e36df78c1bd3ba7943147beaaa1a9c41/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/util/ArraysSupport.java#L112) which appears to be using the unsafe class to cast the values to a long and comparing the long values.