# Guava function to add items to resultant collection based on applying conditions to each item in list

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

I am trying to create a set of items by looking through an existing set and adding each one to a resultant list if it meets certain conditions.  I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this task using some of the Google Guava libraries.  The algorithm is below

```
    final List<String> matchingItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final String li : getItems()) {
        if (li.length() > 5) {
            matchingItems.add(li);
        }
    }
    return matchingItems;
```

Answer (score 2):

## No

There are no more efficient way to write that for-loop than your way<sup>[1]</sup>.

But you can rewrite that in several ways using Guava or Java 8. These will be *slightly* less efficient.

### Using Guava

You can use Guava's [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) class. It's kind of made for your use-case.

Note that you have to create a separate [`Predicate`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html), but you can reuse it at will, of course.

```
Predicate<String> hasLengthGreaterThanFive = new Predicate<String>() {
  @Override public boolean apply(String str) {
    return str.length() > 5;
  }
};
List<String> matchingItems = FluentIterable.from(getItems())
  .filter(hasLengthGreaterThanFive)
  .toList();
```

### Using Java 8

Java 8 makes the previous bit of code much more readable, and you don't need to include Guava.

```
List<String> matchingItems = getItems().stream()
  .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

1: bar some other [byte-code relevant optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006395/fastest-way-to-iterate-an-array-in-java-loop-variable-vs-enhanced-for-statement).