# Use a for-loop or a for-each loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, each

Should we prefer the for-each loop instead of the traditional for-loops? Is the while-loop advantageous?

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Jeff", "Mary", "Elise");

//for-each loop
for(String name: names){
    log(name);
}

//traditional for-loop
for(int index=0; index < 10; ++index){
    log(names.get(index));
}

//Iterator while
Iterator<String> iter1 = names.iterator();
while (iter1.hasNext()) {
    log(iter1.next());
}

//Iterator for loop
for(Iterator<String> iter2 = names.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();){
    log(iter2.next());
}
```

What is the best flavor to use?

Comment: Do whatever you feel like. But hopefully, you'll want to maximize readability. I use `for each` when I don't need the index

Comment: Right tool for the right job.. there is no flavour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226483/java-loop-efficiency-for-vs-foreach

Comment: The traditional loop can load to errors, especially when an index starts from 1, while arrays are zero based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are are same. But some case one is more favourable then others

**Case 1:**

```
//for-each loop
for(String name: names){
    log(name);
}
```

Favourable :

- When you want to iterate over collection
- no adding or deletion over array.
- No need of index of item you iterate

**Case 2:**

```
//traditional for-loop
for(int index=0; index < 10; ++index){
    log(names.get(index));
}
```

Favourable :

- When you want to iterate over collection
- you need to work on index of item you iterate. So for that you always have value of index you currently on.

**Case 3:**

```
Iterator<String> iter1 = names.iterator();
while (iter1.hasNext()) {
    log(iter1.next());
}
```

and

```
//Iterator for loop
for(Iterator<String> iter2 = names.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();){
    log(iter2.next());
}
```

Favourable :

- When you want to iterate over collection
- Addition or deletion take ||ly while iterating.

Comment: I think he already know that, he just want to know which one is better, and I think it's impossible to tell which one is better:)

Comment: @Azad yes it is impposible to tell which one is better. But from the post I didn't found anything which will show that whether he will know this facts or not.

Comment: Loop 2 should be avoided, because this can more easily lead to errors. Typically with the start of your index = 1; list.get(index) and also when using index++ inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Loops 1, 3 and 4 are essentially the same and probably compile to the same bytecode. So use the first one which is more readable.

Loop 2 should be avoided if you don't know what list implementation you are dealing with. In particular, `list.get(i)` can be an O(n) operation on some lists (LinkedLists for example), making the performance of loop 2 an O(n^2) operation = bad.

Answer (score 2):

Options 1 is just a shorten version of 3 and 4. Out of them #1 is preferrable as it easier to write and read. Option 2 may be better in microperformance as it does not create an Iterator object but only in case you use a RandomAccess list like ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `foreach` loop when you want to delete some elements inside this loop. Instead use classic `for` loop, when you can decrease iterator after removing element from collection.

Answer (score 0):

For and foreach differ slightly in performance. They are approximately the same speed. But the foreach loop uses more stack space for local variables.

For more detials about this please refer

```
http://forums.asp.net/t/1209455.aspx/1
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the container implements Iterable, use `for each`, as long as mentioned above you do not need an index. Altought probablly you will use the Objects id field instead of a for id.