# Fastest way to convert ArrayList<Integer> into int[]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

In Java, is below the fastest solution:

```
public convert(ArrayList<Integer> IntegerList) {

    int s = IntegerList.size();
    int[] intArray = new int[s];
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        intArray[i] = IntegerList.get(i).intValue();
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark some different solutions and see for yourself?

Comment: If you want `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, ArrayList has a built in `toArray`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()) method. If you need `int[]`, then this `toArray` is probably not your best choice.

Comment: check out jon skeets answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/960449/639891

Comment: if you want speed, go primitive

Comment: if you want speed change language!

Comment: beware of null values. "Integer" allow null, but "int" cannot

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way is to not use an `ArrayList<Integer>` in the first place. Try `TIntArrayList` which wraps an int[], or use a `int[]` from the start.

If you have to use an ArrayList for some reason and you can't fix it, you are need a way which works and performance is less important.

```
int[] ints = new int[list.size()];
for(int i=0, len = list.size(); i < len; i++)
   ints[i] = list.get(i);
```

Comment: The OP asks the question starting the problem with an `ArrayList<Integer>`, in your solution you do not consider the time you spend to trasform an `ArrayList<Integer>` to a `TIntArrayList`.

Comment: The reason of using ArrayList at the start is that I do not know how much elements it will contain, once I filled in the ArrayList<Integer>, I need a copy for further speedup.

Comment: TIntArrayList can be any size.  Why do you need a copy?

Comment: What is `TIntArrayList`?

Comment: http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html If you don't want to include an additional library, its trivial to implement.

Answer (score 5):

I cant think of any better solution than you have now with plain java. 
However if you use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), You can probably simplify it.

```
public convert(List<Integer> list) {
 int[] ar = Ints.toArray(list); //Ints is the class from Guava library
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void convert(ArrayList<Integer> IntegerList) {
        int[] intArray = new int[IntegerList.size()];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i : IntegerList){
            intArray[count++] = i;
        }
 }
```

**UPDATE** : Q. but is a foreach loop any faster/better/different from a regular for loop?
A. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop)

Comment: I don't know the answer off hand, but is a foreach loop any faster/better/different from a regular for loop? I thought it was the same thing, with an easier way to write it.

Comment: What is a "regular loop"? EDIT: ah I see, the advantage of the foreach- over the for-loop is that it probably uses an iterator instead of indices to access the list, thus not relying on the list providing get(i) in O(1). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work on how a foreach-loop works.

Comment: @BrianJ here you [go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Integer[] intArray = IntegerList.toArray(new Integer[IntegerList.size()]);
```

Comment: The OP is looking for an `int[]`, not an `Integer[]`.

Comment: You can do everything with Integer what you can do with int. thats why i posted it

Comment: Except perform any arbitrary calculation without a loss of performance.