# List iterator causes heap allocations?

Tags: java, android

I'm profiling my android game and surprised to see that:

```
for(O o : myArrayList)
{
}
```

Creates a bunch of heap allocations.

Aside from using a numeric `i++` for loop, is there a better way to get around this problem? Can I preallocate my iterators or something?

Comment: No, there's no performance penalty.

Take a look on this [response][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop

Comment: I'm not concerned with performance, I just want to avoid the garbage collector in my game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop,

```
     for(O o : myArrayList)
     {
     }
```

gets converted to:

```
     for(Iterator<O> iter = myArrayList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
     {
        O o = iter.next();
     }
```

So Iterator objects will be getting allocated on the heap, if you use this pattern.

If you write like:

```
     O o = null;
     for(Iterator<O> iter = myArrayList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
     {
        o = iter.next();
     }
```

or

```
    O o = null;
    Iterator<O> iter = myArrayList.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        o = iter.next();
    }
```

then I think there will not be much of `GC` involvement in the iteration as its only involves assignment of existing object references.

Comment: Will this still cause the GC to get called up a lot more than it should? That is what I want to prevent.

Comment: I think if you declare `O o;` outside the loop then every time it will just change the reference of `o` with elements of the list, which should be better.

Comment: These objects (loop iterators) will most probably exists only in the nursery and will never contribute to a major GC collection.