# Printing a string vertically! Which is best approach in time and complexity?

Tags: java, string

I am writing 3 methods which can print an input string vertically (one line). But I am unaware of the best method since benchmarking with System.nanoTime() considerably changes with large variations, I mean if I calculate the time difference between start and end of the process.
Please suggest which is best or better, opine what you think according to your knowledge.

Code snippet #1

```
/**
 * Prints all the characters in the argument string vertically using loop
 * @param str
 */
public static void toVertStringLoop(String str){

    if(str != null && !"".equals(str)){
        int strLen = str.length();

        for (int i=0; i<strLen; i++){
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Code snippet #2

```
/**
 * Prints all the characters in the argument string vertically using recursion
 * @param str
 */
public static void toVertStringRecur(String str){

    if (str != null && !"".equals(str)){

        System.out.println(str.charAt(0)); //print the first character
        toVertStringRecur(str.substring(1, str.length())); //recursively call removing the first character
    }
}
```

Code snippet #3

```
/**
 * Prints all the characters in the argument string vertically using for-each loop
 * @param str
 */
public static void toVerticalStringIterator(String str){

    //for-each loop needs array or Iterator instance
    for(char ch : str.toCharArray()){
        System.out.println(ch);
    }

}
```

Comment: The first. 2) recursion overhead 3) memory allocation for char array overhead. 3 could be faster assuming the string would not have linear access time (eg.  like a linked list), but there are iterators available for that.

Comment: You already got all the code. Benchmark it and tell us!! I would guess the first one probably comes out on top. You could also try buffering it and only making one System.out call.

Comment: Using recursion is best way of doing process of single data, when comparing process time between other methods.

Comment: this question would be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: when benchmarking try running it e.g. 100000 times and meassure this.

Comment: System.out.println will by far take the most time. For benchmarking better use a StringBuilder and output it's content once.

Comment: sidenote: if (str != null && !"".equals(str)) can be shorter written as if( !"".equals(str) ) because equals checks for null.

Comment: This question belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Sounds like your problem is not understanding how to benchmark in Java. Have a look at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/, for an example framework, or search the Internet for advice on how to perform accurate benchmarking in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Code snippet #3` is better one.Since `Code snippet #2` includes recursive method calls where JVM has to maintain a stack (which reduces performance and increases extra over head to JVM) and where in `Code snippet #1` has same effect of `Code snippet #3` but slightly deffer in performance because of `for-each` loop(Read : 
[Is there a performance difference between a for loop and a for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop))