# Iterator vs For-Each

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iterator

I know there are a lot of similar questions here on SO. But it seems this wasn't discussed before.

In general I want to know, why an Iterator should be used over a For-Each loop, if no element will be removed? So, basically just iterating over a `Collection`, and the only used modifier is `add`.

I'm aware that `Iterator` is the only save option if an element is removed from a `Collection`.
Performance is no argument, because the `For-Each` will be transformed into an Iterator by the compiler.
The `Iterator` is more verbose, so +1 to `For-Each`.

Is there any reliable point to use an Iterator over For-Each in the described scenario?

Comment: I can't think of any compelling reason to, since they are essentially the same thing. I just think the for each looks nicer and is easier to read.

Comment: I assume by foreach, you mean `for(Object o : yourCollection)`? In this case, you must be careful of a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 *"if no element will be removed"*

Comment: You can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you're adding to the underlying collection, too.

Comment: That's what I get for scanning the question. Here is another answer on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop

Comment: I don't think this is an opinion based question. This is just a comparison between to ways for the same thing. If they would be exactly equal one would be redundant.

Comment: @yshavit, yes, but *neither* approach being considered helps avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` when adding elements to the underlying collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `Iterator` loop instead of a foreach loop if

- you need to be able to remove items during processing, OR
- you need to process the last item differently than the others.

Also, an `Iterator` may be more natural if you want to be able to skip an element based on characteristics of its previous element.

Additionally, for `List`s, a `ListIterator` loop may sometimes be more convenient than a foreach loop, as it can provide the indexes of the previous and next elements, and (even apart from the indexes) allows you to recognize the first element of the iteration.  Furthermore, you need a `ListIterator` if

- you have to replace elements in the underlying `List`, OR
- you ever need to back up.