# Filter a ListView with substring search

Tags: java, android, listview, search, filter

I want to filter a `ListView` in such a way that, when user types a word/string in the `EditText` which occurs in the `ListView` item, that item should be filtered.

In the code below, the `EditText` checks the item name from the initial character. I don't need that.

For eg:

List Items: sachin,dhoni,yuvraj...

EditText:v......

The search result should show me *yuvraj*

Here's my code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textlength = editText.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();
            image_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= names[i].length()) {
                    if (editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)names[i].subSequence(0,textlength))) {
                        text_sort.add(names[i]);
                        image_sort.add(imageid[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort));
        }
```

Comment: refer : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: [listview filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android) check this answer.hope it helps

Comment: @kathi...i have updated my code kindly have a look....And also i dint understand the code from that link

Answer (score 2):

It is so simple just this one line in onTextChanged method will do the magic

adapter.getFilter().filter(s):

You  may need to implement Filterable if you have custom adapter

Check this one tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your 'names' variable is an array of Strings containing all the names correct?

Two relevant facts for this :
1) You can iterate through the list with a **for loop.**
2) Additionally, you can can compare strings with  **str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase()**

Also, **keep the reference to the adapter outside the listView.setAdapter() method**, and reassign it whenever you need.
Otherwise you will create anonymous instances of that adapter and eventually flood memory (even if slowly)

```
...
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;
...

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    text_sort.clear();
    image_sort.clear();
    for (String name: names) {         
        if(name.toLowerCase().contains(s.getText().toLowerCase()) {
            text_sort.add(names[i]);
            image_sort.add(imageid[i]);
        }
    }
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort)
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Edit :**

instead of using :

```
  if(name.toLowerCase().contains(s.getText().toLowerCase())
```

which checks if your string contains the string typed, you can use the following

```
  if(name.toLowerCase().startsWith(s.getText().toLowerCase())
```

which checks if the string starts with the string you just typed

Let me know if this solves the issue.

Regards,

Comment: That seems to be working....but could you make it for like eg: sachin tendulkar.....starting character of each word....means if i search 't'....sachin tendulkar should be shown

Comment: Check my update. vote and check if it solves your issue. If not, let me know. regards

Comment: Because the example uses an object for loop instead of an array for loop.. check the difference here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your code doesnt work....but this worked for me if(names[i].indexOf(editText.getText().tostring()!=-1)